# Wordpress sortable custom admin columns

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added multiple custom columns to my WP admin panel:

```
public function admin_column_content($column_name, $post_ID) {
        global $post;
        $progress = (new Question)->get_questions_progress();
        if ($column_name == 'level_1') {
            echo $progress['level_1']['progress'];
        }
        if ($column_name == 'level_2') {
            echo $progress['level_2']['percentage'];
        }
        if ($column_name == 'level_3') {
            echo $progress['level_3']['percentage'];
        }
        if ($column_name == 'address') {
            echo get_field('street') . ' ' . get_field('house_number') . ', ' . get_field('city');
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the first thee options are not based on a (custom) field from that page, but it's a number generated by multiple numbers in the database.

The problem is that I want to make these columns also sortable:

```
public function set_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
        $columns['address'] = 'address';
        $columns['level_1'] = 'level_1';

        return $columns;
    }

    public function school_custom_orderby( $query ) {
        if( ! is_admin() )
            return;

        $orderby = $query->get('orderby');
        $progress = (new Question)->get_questions_progress();

        if('address' == $orderby) {
            $query->set('meta_key','street');
            $query->set('orderby','meta_value');
        } elseif ('level_1' == $orderby) {
            $query->set('meta_key', '');
            $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
        }  
    }
```

The address column is working because I can set the meta_key value to street, which is a ACF field in that custom post type. But how to make level_1, level_2 and level_3 sortable? They don't have a dedicated field in the CPT.

Thanks in advance!

Best wishes
Joeri

Comment: level_1, level_2 and level_3 are the column in a database ?

Comment: No, it's a value based on how many questions are filled in. That value is generated in the functions.php. It's a loop over all questions and answers in the database and if the user has filled in the question, the value will be higher.